# Why Focus not working when keyboard open?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-textformfield

I have a `TextFormField` and above it I have `List` that store `TextFormField` value.
My issue is when I add Items on list, `TextFormField` hide behind the keyboard. I want to keep focus on `TextFormField`.

here is my TextFormField Code.

```
TextFormField(
      cursorColor: Colors.black,             
      onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode); // this line is not working
      },
      style: new TextStyle(
        fontSize: 15.0,
        fontFamily: "Roboto",
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        color: darkGreyColor,
      ),
      controller: _textFieldController,

      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      focusNode: focusNode,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
      onChanged: (text) {
      },
      inputFormatters: [
        new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(200),
      ],
      onSaved: (String? val) {
      },
    ),
```

What I want :

[image]

What I have done:

[image]

Please provide suggestions for how can I achieve it.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there anything body using auto focus?

Comment: No, I want focus on TextFormField only when I add items into list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it by adding  `scrollPadding` into `TextFormField`.

```
TextFormField(
      scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom), // This line works.
      cursorColor: Colors.black,             
      onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode); 
      },
      style: new TextStyle(
        fontSize: 15.0,
        fontFamily: "Roboto",
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        color: darkGreyColor,
      ),
      controller: _textFieldController,

      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      focusNode: focusNode,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
      onChanged: (text) {
      },
      inputFormatters: [
        new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(200),
      ],
      onSaved: (String? val) {
      },
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `TextFormField` to `bottomNavigationBar` inside your `Scaffold` widget

Complete example:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text(''),
  ),
  body: ListView(),
  bottomNavigationBar: TextFormField()
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but My TextFormField is in center of the screen so I can't use bottomNavigationBar.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have set  resizeToAvoidBottomInset to your scaffold. Make it false or just remove it.

or another method is you can give padding when keyboard appears

Comment: resizeToAvoidBottomInset is already false.